# Python, how to combine different excel workbooks into one excel workbook as sheets

Tags: python, excel

is there any way in python by which we can combine different excel workbooks into one excel workbook having sheets containing data of those different excel workbooks?

For example lets say I am  having two excel workbooks 1) emp.xlsx and 2) dept.xlsx i want output as output.xlsx (having worksheets as emp and dept with data of emp.xlsx and dept.xlsx). Request you to please share your thoughts on this.

Regards
Kawaljeet

Comment: The excel sheets do they have the same shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is get each sheet one by one and then create an excel with each one of those sheets. You can use the file name to name the new sheets as in *emp-sheet1*, *emp-sheet2*, *dept-sheet1*, and so on.

The nest example assumes you have two excel files named emp.xlsx and dept.xlsx and generates a new output.xlsx file containing all the sheets and values:

```
#!pip install openpyxl
#!pip install xlrd

import pandas as pd

def get_sheets(filenames):
    '''
    This function generates dataframes from excel sheets.
    Returns:
    - dfs: a list of dataframes one for each sheet
    - sheets: combined names for the new sheets filename+-+sheetname

    '''
    sheets = []
    dfs = []
    for file in filenames:
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheet_names = xl.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheet_names:
            dfs.append(xl.parse(sheet, header=None))
            sheets.append(file.split('.')[0]+'-'+sheet)
    return dfs, sheets


def save_xls(dfs, sheets, xls_path):
    '''
    Saves each dataframe in dfs as a sheet with the name in sheets 
    into the file specified in xls_path
    '''
    with pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for n, df in enumerate(dfs):
            df.to_excel(writer, sheets[n], index = False, header = None)
        writer.save()



filenames = ['emp.xlsx', 'dept.xlsx']
dfs, sheets = get_sheets(filenames) 
save_xls(dfs, sheets, 'output.xlsx')
```